# How to Expose Column in DataTable

Tags: c#

I created class inherited from DataTable. I want to Expose the items like "Name" , "Number"

from the class.  Just like this

```
class MyClass : DataTable
{
  [Column]
  Name

  [Column]
   Number
}
```

so that i can access like row["Name"] = "some";

and i going to use this data table as DataSource to Crystal Report. ( ie from Data menu->Add new DataSource --> object  and select the appropriate class and this will display the Name and Number which i can add to crystal report at design time)

How to achieve this.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own strongly-typed datasets?

Comment: I don't think I understand you, how does what you describe differ from the default behaviour of DataTable and DataRow ?

Comment: Which version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using .Net3.5 I'm new to Crystal report. My database is remote and its accessed through wcf sevice. In client side just i want the customized class which can act as a DataSource for crystal report at design time. So i just drag and drop the fields of the customized class(ie class derived from DataTable or equivalent type). At each time just i'll fill my customized class to fill the Crystal report. * Answer or URL to get the Right way to use the customized class as a Data-source(Design time) for Crystal report is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel.  Trying to create a DataTable that will expose named rows/columns is a pattern that has already been done in .NET 2.0 - If you're using .NET 2.0 take a look at this [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx) which goes through creating Strongly Typed DataSets.

You can also search on google for more information using the keywords [**Strong Typed DataSets**](http://www.google.ca/search?q=strong+typed+datasets)

Answer (score 3):

Using a typed `DataSet` is the best way to do this.  But there are some circumstances in which you might not want or be able to do this.  For instance, you might need the properties to be nullable types, which the typed `DataSet` doesn't support.  (In the typed `DataSet`, each nullable column also has `Set<ColumnName>Null` and `Is<ColumnName>Null` methods, which is pretty gruesome.)

In those cases, you want to take pretty much the same as approach that the typed `DataSet` takes:  subclass `DataRow` and implement the properties there, e.g.:

```
public class MyDataRow : DataRow
{
    public DateTime? SomeDate
    {
        get
        {
            return (this["SomeDate"] is DBNull)
               ? (DateTime?)null
               : this.Field<DateTime>("SomeDate");
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                this["SomeDate"] = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                this["SomeDate"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Two things complicate this, and they have to do with how new rows are constructed.  First, you have to implement a constructor in `MyDataTable` that calls the base constructor:

```
public MyDataRow(DataRowBuilder rb) : base(rb) { }
```

Second (and this is the confusing part), you also have to subclass `DataTable` and override the `NewRowFromBuilder` method.  This makes the `NewRow` method return a `DataRow` object that's actually a `MyDataRow` object (because `NewRow` calls `NewRowFromBuilder`).  If you don't do this, `NewRow` will call the base class's implementation of `NewRowFromBuilder`, which returns a `DataRow`, and you need it to return a `MyDataRow`.

```
public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    protected override DataRow NewRowFromBuilder(DataRowBuilder builder)
    {
        return new MyDataRow(builder);
    }
}
```

Then to create these objects in code, you have something like this:

```
MyDataTable t = new MyDataTable();
MyDataRow r = (MyDataRow) t.NewRow();
```

Note that you still have to cast the return value from `NewRow` (since `NewRow` always returns an object of type `DataRow`).

If you need to handle events on the `MyDataTable`, you'll need to override the event handlers, and have them raise events in the `MyDataRow` object.  Really you should look at the generated code for a typed `DataSet` to see how this works.